# My navbar is not staying sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

**My Navbar won't stay fixed**
I've tried the *`<nav class="fixed-nav-bar>`* and that did not. I've also tried it in css to no avail.

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img src="http://www.ttx.com/Libraries/Main_Gallery/TTXLOGOr_4c_RSG.sflb.ashx" width="25%">
        </img>
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Instruction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: where's your css?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong class. In order to make the `navbar` stick to the top, you need to use `navbar-fixed-top` class rather than `fixed-nav-bar`. Check the code snippet below to see it in action-

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img src="http://www.ttx.com/Libraries/Main_Gallery/TTXLOGOr_4c_RSG.sflb.ashx" width="25%">
        </img>
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Instruction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:60px;">
  <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p>

 <p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Proin eget tortor risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim.</p>

 <p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Proin eget tortor risus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @thenerdhero Glad it helped!

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Bootstrap and you want the navbar fixed at top, you need to add the `navbar-fixed-top` class at the beginning. Like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

I don't think "fixed-nav-bar" is a real Bootstrap class. [Here are the Boostrap docs on fixed navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top).